# How can I select only Unique values from multiple dropdown in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Hi i need to select only Unique value from multiple dropdown, dropwown box is not fix they are rendering dynamically so then could be any number of  dropdown based on dropdown value is in dropdown box.

So i want if user select same value which is already selected in any other dropdown there should be generate a  alert message there

```
<select name="profile1" id="profile1" >
        <option value="1">Delhi</option>
        <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="3">Kanpur</option>

    </select>

<select name="profile1" id="profile2" >
        <option value="1">Delhi</option>
        <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="3">Kanpur</option>

    </select>

<select name="profile1" id="profile3" >
        <option value="1">Delhi</option>
        <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="3">Kanpur</option>

    </select>
```

How can i achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try/research anything?

Comment: IMO better if you use the select `multiple` instead of repeating the same select.

Comment: Would be a more friendly user experience if you disable selections that have already been used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('select').change(function () {

            if ($('select option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]:selected').length > 1)
            {
                alert('you have already selected this item')
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>


<select name="profile1" id="profile1" >
        <option value="1">Delhi</option>
        <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="3">Kanpur</option>

    </select>

<select name="profile1" id="profile2" >
        <option value="1">Delhi</option>
        <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="3">Kanpur</option>

    </select>

<select name="profile1" id="profile3" >
        <option value="1">Delhi</option>
        <option value="2">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="3">Kanpur</option>

    </select> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of you should research some more yourself and not expect us to deliver you the full code.

With that said you can relativly easy do this you will need to check the selected value of the other two other select boxes on change should not be so hard

change function: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Value function: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use this . Honestly, this is easy stuff and any novice like me can write this piece of code .

As the experts said , kindly research before posting questions .

```
$("#profile2").change(function()
{
    var firstvalue=$("#profile1 option:selected").text();
    var secondvalue=$("#profile2 option:selected").text();
    if(firstvalue == secondvalue)
    {
        //alert message 
        //do something
    }
});


$("#profile3").change(function()
{
    var firstvalue=$("#profile1 option:selected").text();
    var secondvalue=$("#profile2 option:selected").text();
    var thirdvalue=$("#profile2 option:selected").text();
    if(firstvalue == thirdvalue || thirdvalue == secondvalue )
    {
        //alert message 
        //do something
    }
});
```